# Google Spreadsheet how to use an if statement over several cells

Tags: google-sheets

Is there a function that allows me to calculate the total value of column B if column A is equal to "some text".
I'm making a budget for myself.

Currently, my Google Spreadsheet looks something like this:

```
----A---- -----B----    
     food         50
  alcohol         20
     food        120
    dance         10
   garden         20
     food         20
    dance         10
```

I would like to get the total amounts like this:

```
----E---- -----E---- 
     food        190
  alcohol         20
    dance         20
   garden         20
```

I can use an if statement on a single cell but how do I do it over several cells and SUM values together? 
So the if statement would be  =if(A1="food",B1,0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SUMIF

```
=SUMIF(range to be matched, criteria,sum range)
```

in your case it would be

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A$7,E1,$B$1:$B$7)
```

assuming `A1:A7` is "food, alochal, dance etc)
`E1` is food (criteria)
and `B1:B7` is the figures (sum range)

Comment: I ended using the SUMIF statement:

    =SUMIF(range to be matched, criteria,sum range)

=SUMIF($A$1:$A$7,E1,$B$1:$B$7)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the function: QUERY.

```
=QUERY(A1:B7; "SELECT A, SUM(B) GROUP BY A LABEL A '', SUM(B) ''")
```

[image: QUERY]

More information: [Query Language Reference](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I used the SUMIF statement for now.
I'm sure I will use the Query function in the spreadsheet later on. Thanks